# What is the general or ideal equation for the radial wave function?

Tags: atoms, molecules

I came across this question on the internet:

> What is the value of $(n + l + r)$ in a given wave function, where $n =$ principle quantum number and $l =$ azimuthal quantum number and $r =$ total number of node present in given wave function.
>
> $$= \frac{1}{81(6\pi)^{1/2}}\left(\frac{Z}{a}\right)^{7/2}r^2\mathrm e^{-Zt/3a}(3\cos^2\theta - 1)$$

But I don't know how to get / interpret the values of $n,$ $l$ and $r$ from the given equation.
Is there any general formula for the radial wave function or I need to calculate it through a series of integrals or something.

Comment: I've rewritten your question from the screenshot for better searchability and appearance, but there is *no* equation, the left side appears as non-existing. Also, please add the source of the question, and you might want to consider rewriting the title as IMO it doesn't correlate well with what is being asked.

Comment: The question is from my school test papers. But I didn't get what the question is about and what is a radial wave function

Comment: But you said in the question body the problem is from the internet; now it's from your school's test papers? Is there any way to have a look at the source?

Comment: This looks like a modified form of one the [normalized hydrogen wavefunctions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html).  What the value of $t$ is in your function is a mystery to me.